# Strictly increasing and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-writing, monotone-functions

I have to prove that if $f\to \infty$ in a stricly increasing way and f is continuous then if $y_0>f(x_0)$, $\exists !\, x_1>x_0$  such that $f(x_1)=y_0$.
My idea is that if f is continuous then it takes all values greater than $f(x_0)$ one only time, but how could I formalize this?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Bolzano's theorem?

Comment: @A.J.Pan-Collantes this can help me to say that f takes all values up to $\infty$, but why one only time?

Comment: As written, the statement is wrong. It should be: if $y_0>f(x_0)$, then $\exists !\, x_1>x_0$ such that $f(x_1)=y_0$. ($x_1$ will depend on $y_0$).

Comment: That is because it is strictly increasing

Comment: @Taladris sorry I have edited the question

Comment: @geetha290krm me too. Maybe I had written not so well the question...

Comment: @geetha290krm It [*was*](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4616144/1) wrong.

Comment: @geetha290krm: it was wrong before being edited. Before edit, it was "$\exists ! x_1>x_0$ such that, if $y_0>f(x_0)$, then $f(x_1)=y_0$". Consider for example $f(x)=x$ and $x_0=0$. Then there is no $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)=1$ and $f(x_1)=2$ despite the fact that $1>f(x_0)$ and $2>f(x_0)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm: same difference as "$\exists y$ such that, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$, $x<y$" and "$\forall x\in\mathbb R$, $\exists y$ such that $x<y$".

Comment: @geetha290krm: I don't think it was (the edit of the question is more recent than your answer by a couple of minutes). I don't know about the downvotes.

Comment: What does $\ \exists !\ $ mean? Does exist? Does not exist?

Comment: Exist only one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, there exists $z>x_0$ such that $f(z)>y_0$. Apply the intermidiate value theorem to $f$ on  $[x_0,z]$. Since $y_0$ lies between $f(x_0)$ and $f(z)$ there exists $x_1$ with $f(x_1)=y_0$. $x_1$ is unique because $f$ is strictly increasing.

[If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then  we can neither have $x_1 <x_2$ nor $x_2<x_1$ by strict monotonicity].